# Page Redirect ErrorPage.aspx

Tags: jmeter

I am executing performance tests in the Jmeter. However, I am an issue in response data. It's showed the following message:

1|#||4|58|pageRedirect||%2fDFE_PT%2fErrorPage.aspx%3fOriginId%3d637772668313066879|

Meantime, the page contains two IDs that is changed each iteration on the page. I've configured and controlled those IDs through regular expression. I do not get because this message is being displayed. This is displayed in all requests.

Has someone any tip to overtake this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are coming from the Regular Expression Extractors really contain the anticipated values, you can do this using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/).

If the variables have the values perform the further cross-check of the network footprint of your JMeter test and the real browser.

1. Capture the request(s) which is being sent by the browser using browser developer tools (or maybe even better a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp))
2. Do the same for the request(s) which is(are) being sent from JMeter
3. Compare everything:

   - [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)
   - [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
   - Request body

   all should be the same (apart from dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))

Given JMeter will be sending the same request as browser does - you will get the same response.